# Simple HTML DOM load() returning null

Tags: php, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

I am trying to extract everything from within the `<body>` tags of a normal HTML document.

```
function extractHtml($html){

    $doc = new simple_html_dom();
    $html = $doc->load($html);

    return $doc->find("body")->innertext;
}
```

The `$html` being passed is a full HTML document, although when it is loaded using `load()` is returns null. This then obviously causes the find() to produce a notice

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

What could be the reason for the load() returning null?

In the past I have done;

```
function extractHtml($html){
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

    // get everything inside of <body>
    $body = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');
    if($body && 0<$body->length) {
        $body = $body->item(0);
    }

    $search = array('<body', 'body>');
    $replace = array('<div', 'div>');
    return str_replace($search, $replace, $dom->saveHTML($body));
}
```

Although I now need this to work in older versions of PHP to solve this error

> Warning: DOMDocument::saveHTML() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given

Which was the reason for testing with simple html dom.

**EDIT:**
When testing if I copy the example from the documentation by changing the HTML as follows, I still get the same error.

```
$doc->load("<html><body>Hello!</body></html>");
```

Comment: Are you sure the `find()` produces the notice, and not the `->innertext`? As in, the `$doc` is probably not `NULL`, but the find `find` is returning `null` ?

Comment: According to the doc, http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm, it works only on PHP 5+....so when you say `Although I now need this to work in older versions of PHP to solve this error`, it might have an issue with PHP v<5

Comment: @Nanne yes you are correct because when I remove the find("body") it works. Although why could it not find the body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that find returns an `array`, not an object.

From: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

> // Find all anchors, **returns a array of element objects**
>       $ret =$html->find('a');

(emph mine).